# Can i send direct messages to my clients facebook followers using API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I have seen services advertising that they can message the followers of pages and accounts on Facebook. I have gone over lots of different Facebook API's and several interesting threads on here but cant find a definitive answer.

Is is possible to directly message via a bot users who like a page providing obviously we have a valid admin token for that page?

Answer (score 1):

> Is is possible to directly message via a bot users who like a page

No, that is not possible.

All communication via the Messenger platform API (basis for “bots” in Facebook terminology) requires that the user initiates it.

---

And it would probably be considered *spam* by most people - just because I liked your page, does not mean I want to be contacted by you in any way beyond that. *Posting* to your page is the designated way of communicating with the people that follow your page.